# RGB + Depth Encoding for CNNs

Tags: neural-network, classification, deep-learning, feature-selection, image-recognition

I need to train a CNN ([YOLO](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/) to be precise) on RGB + depth information. I have the RGB input as a separate PNG file and the depth map as a separate PNG file. These PNG files are 8 bit depth, 3 channel files. I need to create a single PNG file of 16 bit depth, 3 channels which is essentially a combination of both the original files. What is the right way to combine / encode RGB + depth information?

Data 1: R, G, B channels of 8 bits each
Data 2: D1, D2, D3 channels of 8 bits each
Required: C1, C2, C3 channels of 16 bits each

**Current idea**

I'm currently using a bitwise shifting.
C1 = R << 8 | D1
C2 = G << 8 | D2
C3 = B << 8 | D3
(shift by 8 bits left and then OR)

**Questions**

- Notice that the channels left shifted (R, G and B) obtain higher significant bits and dominate over D1, D2, and D3 while forming C1, C2, C3. The CNN loses the information present in the depth map. Is there a better encoding?
- A small note about the depth map. The depth information requires 16
  bits and is contained in D2 and D3. D1 channel is a pseudo channel
  with only gray scale information of the image. The final encoding
  should focus on D2 and D3 more.

**Another idea**

To make sure no channel dominates over the other, I was thinking of interleaving the two 8 bit sequences to form a 16 bit sequence. If channel R has `b1, b2, ..., b8` bit sequence and channel D1 has `bb1, bb2, ..., bb8` bit sequence then the combined 16 bit C1 channel will have `b1, bb1, b2, bb2, ..., b8, bb8` bit sequence. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Why aren't you just making more channels? Your ideas will all result in a lot of information loss

Comment: I agree. More channels are the way to go. But I'm constrained by the network architecture of YOLO which works with only 3 input channels. Therefore I need to 'simulate' 6 channels by making the combined 16 bit sequence composed of seemingly two independent 8 bit sequences.

Comment: Why are you constrained? YOLO architecture is easily extended to more channels and pretrained networks will not work if you 'simulate' these 6 channels into 3

Comment: @JanvanderVegt I'm not using a pretrained network since I'll be training on my own dataset. So that should not be an issue. About extending YOLO, yes I'm exploring that too. But it looks daunting in Darknet.

Comment: You should combine your 2 images into 4-channel RGBD training data at the point the image data is loaded and turned into features for the network. There should be no need for an interim PNG image. If you are using a pre-existing script/implementation that loads images from disk to train with, it is the image loader and just the first layer of NN model that you need to change.